# HTML - Insert text inside div container

Tags: html, css, text

I am using div because I want to colour not the whole border but the external corner, it works but now what I want to do is to add a text/link at the centre of the four corners.

If I am going to do that the text stays quadruple on each corner and change even the position of the div corner.

Is there a better way to do that?

It seems simple as it is but I have been in stock with this for days, this is my code in a snippet:

```css
html,
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.wholeDivDom {
  margin: 0.7%;
}

.outer {
  width: 350px;
  height: 120px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  width: 10%;
}

.outer:after {
  content: "";
  right: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}

.outer:before {
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}

.inner:before {
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}

.inner:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<body >
  <header>
    <div class="wholeDivDom">
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```

Comment: you mean like "hello" there is text in each side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `span` tag to add your text and apply `position: absolute` to it. Then giving it `left:50%` and `top:50%` with `transform: translate(-50%,-50%);` should do the trick.

```css
html,
body {
  color: #fff;
  background: #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.wholeDivDom {
  margin: 0.7%;
}

.outer {
  width: 350px;
  height: 120px;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

div:before,
div:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 20%;
  width: 10%;
}

.outer:after {
  content: "Hello";
  right: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}

.outer:before {
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  border-top: 3px solid #fff;
}

span {
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
}

.inner:before {
  bottom: 0;
  border-left: 3px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}

.inner:after {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  border-right: 3px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #fff;
}
```

```html
<body >
  <header>
    <div class="wholeDivDom">
      <div class="outer">
        <div class="inner">
            <span>Text goes here</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
</body>
```